# How are relationships between clauses marked in languages that lack sentential embedding?

Tags: syntax, embedding, clauses

I have heard that there are a few languages that lack sentential embedding.   If this is the case, what grammatical devices do they use instead of adverbial clauses, complement clauses, and noun-modifying clauses?

Comment: What languages have you heard this about? BTW, subordinate clauses are not the only kind of sentential embedding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By relying on inference, parataxis can do the job. Compare the a-examples (parataxis) with the b-examples (subordination) below.

```
1) a) Go fetch the urn, the one on the mantlepiece
   b) Go fetch the urn that is on the mantlepiece
2) a) The sun was shining bright. We went for a walk.
   b) The sun was shining bright, so we went for a walk.
```

There are still rules though. In the second parataxis-example (2a), the latter sentence is generally assumed to happen simultaneously or after the first sentence. What happens first goes first, and a cause would be mentioned before the effect etc.

The [Wikipedia-page on parataxis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parataxis) isn't very useful as it concentrates too much on parataxis in English for poetic effect, but now you know one more term to look for in reference grammars at least!